# Check a stencil bit, and write to another bit

Tags: opengl, bitmask, stencil-buffer

I'm rendering reflective surfaces in my 3D engine. I need to perform two stencil operations. First, I draw out the reflective surface with depth testing to find visible areas of the surface. I then need to draw out models into a G-Buffer, which is also stencilled to find areas to draw my skybox.

- Draw Surface: always draw, write bit #1
- Draw Models: draw only if bit #1 is set, write bit #2

How would I do this using OpenGL? I'm unsure of the relationship between the glStencilFunc ref and mask values, and the glDepthMask value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [glStencilOp](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glStencilOp.xml)
- [glStencilFunc](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glStencilFunc.xml)
- [glStencilMask](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glStencilMask.xml)

The docs are quite specific, but it's not always intuitive or obvious what to do if you simply want to create and then activate a mask. I use these as a simple starting point...

## Create the mask

Clear the stencil buffer to zeroes and write 1s to all pixels you draw to.

```
void createStencilMask()
{
    // Clear the stencil buffer with zeroes.
    // This assumes glClearStencil() is unchanged.
    glClear(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Enable stencil raster ops
    // 1. Enables writing to the stencil buffer (glStencilOp)
    // 2. If stencil test (glStencilFunc) fails, no frags are written
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    // sfail GL_KEEP - keep original value if stencil test fails
    // dpfail GL_KEEP - also keep if the stencil passes but depth test fails
    // dppass GL_REPLACE - write only if both pass and you'd normally see it
    //                     this writes the value of 'ref' to the buffer
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE);

    // func GL_ALWAYS - the stencil test always passes
    // ref 1 - replace with ones instead of zeroes
    // mask 1 - only operate on the first bit (don't need any more)
    // Assumes glStencilMask() is unchanged
    glStencilFunc(GL_ALWAYS, 1, 1);
}
```

Call the above function, and draw your stuff. You can set [glDepthMask](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDepthMask.xml) and [glColorMask](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) so this doesn't actually affect the current colour/depth and your scene, only the stencil buffer.

## Draw, using the mask

Only draw to pixels with 1s from the previous step.

```
void useStencilMask()
{
    // Enable stencil raster ops
    glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

    // Just using the test, don't need to replace anything.
    glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);

    // Only render if the current pixel stencil value is one.
    glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 1);
}
```

Draw and then leave the test disabled `glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST)` when you're done.

## Reading and writing different bits

Now to focus on your question...

This bit's a little tricky because the same `ref` value of `glStencilFunc()` is used in *both* the stencil test and as the value to replace. However, you can get around this with masks:

1. Use `mask` in `glStencilFunc()` to ignore bits when testing/reading.
2. Use `glStencilMask()` to stop certain bits from getting written.

In your case you don't need to mask out the first bit from being written because it's already set. Simply update `useStencilMask()` to `glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_REPLACE)` and `glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 3, 1);`. Because `mask` is `1`, only the first bit is used in the test for equality. However the whole `ref` of 3 (which is `0b11`) is written. You *could* use `glStencilMask(2)` (which is `0b10`) to stop the first bit from being written but it's already one so it doesn't matter.

You could also make use of `GL_INCR` which would set the second bit and remove the first. Or perhaps clear with ones and use `GL_ZERO` to mark both your bits.

Comment: Aaaah, so the mask parameter to glStencilFunc masks the ref value too? I thought that it only masked the value currently in the buffer. Thanks!